# windows 10 not detected after restart

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

Basically I have a custom desktop and it does this weird thing where it boots up normally if I press the on/off power button but if i select restart in the power options inside the OS, the computer restarts but goes straight to BIOS and when I look at it in that same session it does not detect the windows operating system however it does detect the hard drive that contains the OS.

When it restarts and goes to BIOS, the only way to get back to the OS is by pressing and holding the power button and then turning it back on with the power button. when I turn it on normally it does detect the operating system

this started happening soon after installing windows 10, also the BIOS only does not detect the OS on restart. the BIOS does detect the OS when powered on normally after a shutdown

P.s. I don't know if this an alright description but Im going to edit this with pictures soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your computer does not use secure boot and that the hard drive / efi is at the top priority on boot, then I would suggest checking to see if your motherboard has a bios update. Because I said that **DOES NOT MEAN I SUGGEST YOU UPDATE**, updating your motherboard is a very dangerous process and should only be used as a last resort. It is very easy to permanently brick your computer when doing such a process, and can even damage other components in your chassis.